# Result of call to 'subscribe(onNext:onError:onCompleted:onDisposed:)' is unused

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rxalamofire

I am trying to create function which return Observable<(HTTPURLResponse, Any)> using RxAlamofire:

```
func getResponse(credentialData: Credentials, ulr: String)->Observable<(HTTPURLResponse, Any)>{
        let credentialData = "\(credentialData.username):\(credentialData.password)".data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!
        let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedString()
        let headers = ("Authorization", "Basic \(base64Credentials)")
        let header = HTTPHeaders.init(dictionaryLiteral: headers)

        return Observable.create{ observer in
            requestJSON(.get, ulr, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header)
            .subscribe(onNext: { response in
                observer.onNext(response)
                } ,
        onError: { error in
            observer.onError(error)
            })
        return Disposables.create()
        }
    }    
}
```

but I get this below warning:-

> Result of call to 'subscribe(onNext:onError:onCompleted:onDisposed:)'
>   is unused

How to fix it? After adding `.disposed(by: disposeBag)` my function isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you have to add your request into a `DisposeBag` :

```
return Observable.create { observer in
        requestJSON(.get, ulr, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header)
            .subscribe(onNext: { response in
                observer.onNext(response)
            }, onError: { error in
                observer.onError(error)
            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        return Disposables.create()
    }
```

That should works.

Comment: function getResponse don't return anything, when I do like in your example

Comment: Could you provide an example of use of getResponse ?

Comment: `let aPIManager = APIManager()
aPIManager.getResponse(credentialData: credentials, ulr: "https://api.github.com/authorizations").subscribe{response in
                /*code*/
            }`

here no observable was emited

Comment: I think you have the same problem as your question, you should add to a `DisposeBag` too `aPIManager.getResponse(credentialData: credentials, ulr: "api.github.com/authorizations").subscribe {response in /*code*/ }.disposed(by: disposeBag)`

Comment: ok, I added it to a `DisposeBag`, but in `subscribe {response in /*code*/ }` no one emit

Comment: If you put a breakpoint to `observer.onNext(response)` or `observer.onError(error)` do you going through ?

Comment: Try to implement `onCompleted:` and `onDisposed:` to understand what's wrong with your observables. the warning should be silenced by `.disposed(by: disposeBag)`, so for a new problem you should open another question with more details.

Comment: I implemented it, I going through `onDisposed:` only